# What does 'updates pending' in Google Developer Console means

Tags: android

I was updating screenshots for my app on Developer Console but when I finished updating them and clicked 'Publish' it showed me message 'Update pending' disabling the 'Update App'  button. Can anyone help me in this.

Comment: I'm getting the same thing except that I've published an app update 7 hours ago and I'm still not seeing it on the play store. Interestingly enough an update for another app which I published 2 hours ago is live already. Probably something went haywire on Google's end, just have to wait it out.

Comment: probably you are having this as first time publish rather than update it..

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Why it says "Update pending" is because it takes Google Play some time to publish your changes all over Google Play since it's a big network. It usually takes 1-2 hours before the changes is visible.

**Update 8 April**

The time for updates might now take more time since Google is now reviewing the apps that are submitted.

http://appleinsider.com/articles/15/03/17/google-follows-apples-lead-introduces-human-app-review-team-for-the-play-store

Comment: For me, this is taking up to a day or similar.

Comment: @Jonny Google has recently started to review apps that are submitted, that might be your issue in this case. That's it's pending a form of review

Comment: That's funny because the binary in fact is just an alpha one for internal testing. I just learned that the alpha and beta stages just can't be used for internal testing. Flinging binaries to HockeyApp and publishing to testers is instantaneous.

Comment: @Jonny I've never used HockeyApp but I can understand that it's faster deployment than Google Play. But that isn't so hard to understand why, when Google Play is a bigger network and HockeyApp is supposed to be a tool for development when fast deployment means faster development.

At first I though you meant about publishing the apps for the public, but if it takes ~24 hours for alpha and beta testing that's horrible.

Comment: Yes, the Google alpha/beta thing is just not feasible for a normal development cycle. I just wonder who would use it for what use case. Anyway this has been my first attempt at uploading Android binaries anyway, and I can assume some beginner mistakes, although I did have one app totally suspended for violation of SOMETHING the other day. We appealed, and got the app back online today with no reason given and no apologies. Even coming from iOS/apple background, I'm not impressed. We live and learn.

Comment: @Jonny Coming from an ios/apple background that's very impressive considering apple takes 7 times as long and is much more strict.  And in my experience even now it's a very quick review process.

Comment: Just to note, I just released an app late last night (4am MST) and it was completed by the time I came into work (1PM MST).  And that was published for production

Answer (score 25):

**UPDATE FEBRUARY 2021**

Currently, average waiting times are:

- New Apps, new developers, 1 to 7 days.
- New Apps, seasoned developers, 1 to 4 days.
- Updates, 24h to 36h, sometimes less.

This is purely based on my experienced and colleagues’ feedback, there’s no inside information, Google has none to my knowledge.

The "whys" about why this process is so slow and how Google review goes:
https://www.jazzcoding.com/google-play-app-review-times/

Comment: @Halen Wood , more than 30h, and my app update still in (UPDATE PENDING) state

Comment: @pic I know, I just updated the review times, they may take longer, mostly during weekends (which I guess it's your case) let me know when you have some kind of feedback. Thanks.

Comment: thank you for your reply, Almost 3 days and still (update pending) I have contacted the support and they tell me I should just wait, I'm pretty sure there's a problem, I didn't face any problem like that before, Previously it takes 1 or 2 hours, but now it's days to make update live on Google Play

Comment: Those 1 or 2 hours are long long gone, nowadays it's a very slow process.

Comment: I have been waiting now for 48 hours, still pending

Comment: @HelenWood first app, it was published the 4th day

Comment: @Alan as I said... 1 to 6 days. Thanks for sharing.

Comment: Three app on review. One Update, and two new App. I've uploaded the update first and then the two new app. After three hours the first new App is Published. the others are still waiting.

Comment: Yeah, weird thing is that some Apps goes through in hours, like good old times.

Comment: for some people even it takes 10 days https://support.google.com/googleplay/thread/12736730?hl=en

Comment: @HelenWood. Today it's seven!!